# Multi-language auto-escape in Freemarker

Tags: javascript, html, xss, freemarker

I recently turned on auto-escaping in Freemarker and change my `.ftl` files to `.ftlh` to make sure they get formatted/escaped as HTML. However, this means that any inline `<script>` or `<style>` tags get HTML escaped, which is not what I want. I can solve the problem by doing this:

```
<script>
    [#outputformat "JavaScript"]
         jQuery(".stuff").blah();
    [/#outputformat]
</script>
```

This works, but it seems like a lot of work to add this wrapper around the contents of every script tag. It seems it would make sense to have a OutputFormat that is smart enough to detect script/style tags and use the right format, or alternatively custom tags that have the same effect as the above. Something like:

```
[@smartscript]
    jQuery(".stuff").blah();
[/@smartscript]
```

Does anything like this (or anything else that solves this problem) already exist? I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than pre-processing templates in a custom `TemplateLoader` (which wraps another `TemplateLoader` and filters the `Reader` returned by it), there's no solution for this currently. Macros won't help either, because `#outputformat` doesn't have runtime effect. It just associates sections of the FTL source code with an output format.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anywhere I can read more about the order and effect of how #outputformat and a macro like @script are evaluated? I'm having trouble finding it in the docs.

Comment: There's a chapter about auto-escaping and output formats: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html#dgui_misc_autoescaping_overrideoformat. See the paragraph that says "each position in a template has an associated output format".

Comment: Ah, great. Thanks!